# How come we have such a strong Australian contingent?

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of answers by different people that link to the Australian SPCA, I'm guessing most of these people are actually Australian.

Given most SE sites I've been on usually have North American as their strongest contingent (which can be a disadvantage as it seems to sometimes result in US-specific answers), I'm genuinely curious what attracted so many Australians to this particular SE site.

Comment: Might it be that as there is not (as far as I am aware) an Australian Coders Association to link to for Q/A on SO, you assume those you see on SO are all from the same country as you?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Not at all, I'm from mainland Europe and most other SE sites to me come across as having a strong US user base. I'm really just curious. But maybe it's all in my imagination.

Comment: I am really not sure why this needs to be asked at all - different sites will attract different users, and it really doesn't matter where people are from.

Comment: Questions about a site's audience seem on-topic to me *if relevant to the content of the site*.  For example, one of the religion sites has a meta question asking why members of a particular sub-group don't participate there.  That's healthy.  If there are pet-related issues specific to certain areas, that too would be relevant.  But it appears that this question is based on a faulty premise (misunderstanding the ASPCA references).  I don't think it should be closed as "primarily opinion-based" or "off-topic" (the current nominations), but it doesn't feel very helpful either.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It was pure curiosity on my part and I wasn't expecting it to gain much traction. However, I also wouldn't know where else to put the question. If I was deeply interested in the topic, I could probably post a question on meta.SO about demographics of different SE sites. But maybe a simpler & more helpful question would have been to ask where users are from and what attracted them to the site. Opinion-based is not really a valid close reason for meta, IMO, because meta questions often explicitly try to get the community's opinion consensus. But I don't mind it being closed at all.

Comment: @ThomasH, I'm primarily responding to the four close votes currently registered against the question, not so much to you for asking it.  Sorry for being unclear.  I think you have a question born of of natural curiosity and apparently a mistaken impression (sounds like we *don't* actually have that many Australians).  Shrug; it happens.

Answer (score 5):

The [ASPCA](http://www.aspca.org/about-us) is the American Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals. aspca.org

The [RSPCA](http://www.rspca.org.au/) is the Royal Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals, is an Australian organisation. rspca.org.au

The [RSPCA](http://www.rspca.org.uk/home) is the Royal Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals, is the United Kingdom organisation. rspca.org.uk

As for many Australian's being here, I know of two others. Of 177 users, I am not sure this is a flood of Australians.

As for understanding how to care for animals in the Northern Hemisphere, well it is difficult as all our writing is upside down. It takes forever to write up answers here, as I have to run  all the questions and answers through an interpreter. It's hard work.

Comment: +10 " well it is difficult as all our writing is upside down. It takes forever to write up answers here, as I have to run all the questions and answers through an interpreter. It's hard work"

Comment: I hear the toilets flush upwards too, crazy stuff.